# My optocoupler doesn't give more than 1.86V

Tags: opto-isolator

I didn’t have anything else so I am trying to use a 4N35 optocoupler to power a 5V relay with an ESP8266 which only gives 3.3V maximum.

When I connect the circuit as shown in the image the output gives a maximum voltage of 1.86V. I have tried with a 5V and a 9V supply but the value stays the same.

I don't have any idea what is going on since is the first time I used a optocoupler with 6 pins.

I changed the image to a better one of the full circuit:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the output to be lower (to turn the LED on brighter) or higher (to turn the LED dimmer)?

Comment: Show how you are driving the input side of the optocoupler.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Which output voltage did you measure? Please show us the whole picture of the circuit. When you conntect the Pin1 (4N35) directly to a processor pin, the internal output structure of the processor usually limits the maximum current, so the voltage at pin1 is only limited by the forward voltage of the diode (4N35).

Comment: Please show us your _actual_ circuit including relay and connection to the ESP8266, and voltages at pin 1 and pin 5 when the MCU output is high and low. What is the coil resistance of your 5V relay? What drive strength do you have the ESP8266 output set to?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. Problems with OP's circuit.*

1. You have no current limiting on the opto-LED. The [RN35 datasheet #](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83717/4n35x.pdf) says that the forward voltage of the LED is 1.2 to 1.5 V at 10 mA. You are applying 3.3 V. The datasheet also says that the **absolute maximum** current is 60 mA. You need to add a 100 Ω resistor at (1). You are probably being saved by the current limiting on the output of your microcontroller but either the micro or the LED will probably be destroyed soon.

[image]

2. You have connected the battery backwards. Pin 5 of the opto-isolator is the transistor's collector. Current flows from collector to emitter.
3. If your meter reads 1.86 V across a short-circuit (as shown in your diagram) then it is broken. You should be measuring the voltage across RLY1's coil.

[image]

*Figure 3. Current transfer ratio.*

4. The current transfer ratio tells you how much current you can expect from the transistor for a given current on the LED. You can see in Figure 3 that at the nominal 10 mA LED current you can get 100% transfer ratio which means that the most you should be expecting to control with the transistor is 10 mA. I doubt your 5 V relay will switch on at 10 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNhGSM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 4. A simple NPN switch will do the job.*

Answer (score 0):

Wrong polarity on the transistor of 4N35. Swap 4 and 5.
Rock it.

Comment: That's not going to be enough, Bill. The CTR of the isolator is 100% so there won't be enough current for the relay. Hit the edit link if you want to improve your answer. Bear in mind that many of our users are not native English speakers. I am but I don't know what "rock it" is meant to communicate.